# Calling dylib functions in Office for Mac VBA

Tags: c++, macos, vba, dylib

I am attempting to call a simple function that is stored in a simple dylib file, from a simple Word for Mac macro,

I'm creating the .dylib with Xcode5 on OS-X Mountain Lion, and calling it from Word for Mac 2011.

first the libWord.dylib:

**Test.h**

```
#ifndef __Word__Test__
#define __Word__Test__

bool testFunc();

#endif
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"

bool testFunc(){
    return true;
}
```

and the macro:

**Word Macro**

```
Private Declare Function testFunc Lib "/Users/usrName/Documents/libWord.dylib" () As Boolean

Sub TestLibFunc()

    Dim b As Boolean
    b = testFunc
    StatusBar = b

End Sub
```

The Macro can find the dylib (which I have placed in the above directory), but keeps throwing:

**"Run-time error '453':
Specified DLL function not found"**

I have also tried declaring the function as part of a class:

```
class testClass{
    static bool testFunc();
}

bool testClass::testFunc(){
    return true;
}
```

and then tried to call it using both the above Declare statement, and one with an alias:

```
Private Declare Function testFunc Lib "/Users/usrName/Documents/libWord.dylib" Alias "testClass::testFunc" () As Boolean
```

I also tried replacing "/" with ":" in the library path name, all of which give the same result.

So, what am I missing? as far as all the examples I've seen go:

[VBA Shell function in Office 2011 for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136798/vba-shell-function-in-office-2011-for-mac)

[Return string to VBA in MacOSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919066/return-string-to-vba-in-macosx)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b060f291-0754-4e85-a7b9-e64259e6baad/vba-using-shared-library-office-2011-mac?forum=isvvba

The above *should* work (in the same way the remote control *should* be exactly where you left it).
but obviously I must be doing something wrong and any pointers as to where to look would be welcome (the more obvious and shaming the better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! (ugh, it was *there* the whole time?)

[This tutorial](http://blackcatsoftware.us/dynamic-libraries-dylib-for-office-using-xcode-5/) succinctly covers the basics of calling .dylib functions from VBA.

Just be sure to [install Xcode Command-Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools) so that you can use the nm command to get the symbols from your library.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking up the mangled name, I suspect the easiest way is to wrap your function declarations:

```
extern "C" {
bool testFunc();
}
```