# How to read/write memory on Mac OS X with VBA?

Tags: vba, macos, winapi, declare, kernel32

On Windows the declared function `RtlMoveMemory` provides a way to copy a block of bytes from one address to another:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "kernel32" ( _
                              ByVal dest As LongPtr, _
                              ByVal src As LongPtr, _
                              ByVal size As LongPtr)
```

What is the equivalent on Mac OS X ?

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26694931/excel-vba-how-change-this-class-to-work-for-Mac-excel-2011.html  has an accepted answer. Don't know if you're aware of that?

Comment: @Luuklag As far as I saw, they wrote a custom `alloc`. That will not help here, as `RtlMoveMemory`access all process memory.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470863/calling-dylib-functions-in-office-for-mac-vba and https://blackcatsoftware.us/dynamic-libraries-dylib-for-office-using-xcode-5/ ? You might be able to follow similar convention to call memmove from the C lib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the equivalent on Mac OS X ?

Short answer:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" _
                                 ( _
                                    ByVal dest As LongPtr _
                                  , ByVal src As LongPtr _
                                  , ByVal size As LongLong _
                                  ) _
                        As LongPtr
```

Long answer: Depends ;)

---

The following is a fully fledged example which uses conditional compilation* to allow it to work on any Mac/Windows/32-bit/64-bit computer. It also demonstrates the two different ways to declare and call the function (by Pointer and by Variable).

```
#If Mac Then
  #If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory_byPtr Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (ByVal dest As LongPtr, ByVal src As LongPtr, ByVal size As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory_byVar Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (ByRef dest As Any, ByRef src As Any, ByVal size As Long) As LongPtr
  #Else
    Private Declare Function CopyMemory_byPtr Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (ByVal dest As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal size As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CopyMemory_byVar Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (ByRef dest As Any, ByRef src As Any, ByVal size As Long) As Long
  #End If
#ElseIf VBA7 Then
  #If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory_byPtr Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dest As LongPtr, ByVal src As LongPtr, ByVal size As LongLong)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory_byVar Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef dest As Any, ByRef src As Any, ByVal size As LongLong)
  #Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory_byPtr Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dest As LongPtr, ByVal src As LongPtr, ByVal size As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory_byVar Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef dest As Any, ByRef src As Any, ByVal size As Long)
  #End If
#Else
  Private Declare Sub CopyMemory_byPtr Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dest As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal size As Long)
  Private Declare Sub CopyMemory_byVar Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef dest As Any, ByRef src As Any, ByVal size As Long)
#End If


Public Sub CopyMemoryTest()

  Dim abytDest(0 To 11) As Byte
  Dim abytSrc(0 To 11) As Byte
  Dim ¡ As Long

  For ¡ = LBound(abytSrc) To UBound(abytSrc)
    abytSrc(¡) = AscB("A") + ¡
  Next ¡

  MsgBox "Dest before copy = #" & ToString(abytDest) & "#"
  CopyMemory_byVar abytDest(0), abytSrc(0), 4
  MsgBox "Dest during copy = #" & ToString(abytDest) & "#"
  CopyMemory_byPtr VarPtr(abytDest(0)) + 4, VarPtr(abytSrc(0)) + 4, 4
  MsgBox "Dest during copy = #" & ToString(abytDest) & "#"
  CopyMemory_byPtr VarPtr(abytDest(8)), VarPtr(abytSrc(8)), 4
  MsgBox "Dest after copy = #" & ToString(abytDest) & "#"

End Sub

Public Function ToString(ByRef pabytBuffer() As Byte) As String
  Dim ¡ As Long
  For ¡ = LBound(pabytBuffer) To UBound(pabytBuffer)
    ToString = ToString & Chr$(pabytBuffer(¡))
  Next ¡
End Function
```

**Explanation:**

The Mac version of the CopyMemory function returns a result whilst the Win version does not. (The result is the dest pointer, unless an error occurred. See the memmove reference [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memmove.html).) Both versions, however, can be used in exactly the same way, without brackets.

The declare differences are as follows:

- 64-bit Mac/Win VBA7:

  - Use the `PtrSafe` keyword
  - Use the `Any` type for *all* `ByRef` parameters
  - Use the `LongPtr` type for `ByVal` handle/pointer parameters/return values
  - Use the `LongLong` type appropriately for other return values/parameter
- 32-bit Win VBA7:

  - Use the `PtrSafe` keyword
  - Use the `Any` type for *all* `ByRef` parameters
  - Use the `LongPtr` type for `ByVal` handle/pointer parameters/return values
  - Use the `Long` (***not*** `LongLong`) type appropriately for other return values/parameter
- 32-bit Mac/Win VBA6:

  - No `PtrSafe` keyword
  - Use the `Any` type for *all* `ByRef` parameters
  - Use the `Long` type for `ByVal` handle/pointer parameters/return values
  - Use the `Long` type appropriately for other return values/parameter

**Caveats:**

- Tested on Mac Excel 2016 64-bit.
- Tested on Windows Excel 2007 32-bit.

  - Seems Excel 2007 has issues related to double word alignment. In this
    example:

    `CopyMemory_byVar abytDest(0), abytSrc(0), 4 '-> ABCD
     CopyMemory_byVar abytDest(1), abytSrc(1), 8 '-> ABCDEFGHI`

    `CopyMemory()` skips all copying until a double word alignment is
    reached (3 skips in this case), then continues copying from the 4th
    byte.

---

> Note: If you are curious about my variable naming convention, it is based on [RVBA](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp).

*<sub>The ***correct*** way.</sub>

Comment: Very clear, but these are slightly excessive I think: You check `#If VBA7` - this ensures `LongPtr` is defined. There is no need then to check `#If Win64`. `Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory_byPtr Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dest As LongPtr, ByVal src As LongPtr, ByVal size As LongPtr)` will work on both 32 and 64 bit systems. Also, in your Mac declarations, you use `Long` on 64 bit - is this correct? For windows, `size/length` in `RtlMoveMemory` is of type `SIZE_T` which is an alias to `ULONG_PTR` - i.e. VBA should use `LongPtr` - is the same true for Macs' `memmove`?

Answer (score 2):

I looked up `RtlMoveMemory()` on msdn.microsoft.com and it appears to simply copy a number of bytes from one address to another, handing the special case of overlapping memory.

The Darwin equivalent is `void* memmove(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)`

The primitive/faster version is `void* memcpy(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t n)`, which does not handle overlapping memory regions.

Do a `man memmove` for the details.

Comment: How do you access `memmove`/`memcpy` from VBA, though? I'm assuming the OP is writing a VBA macro for use on Windows as well as Mac OS X, or porting a script from Windows to Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes, `RtlMoveMemory` is a public wrapper around `memmove`. The equivalent of `memcpy` would be `RtlCopyMemory`. The question, though, is why you'd need to do this. People use `RtlMoveMemory` in VBA to interact with the Windows API. If you're interacting with the Cocoa APIs, you should probably call Cocoa memory management functions instead of low-level standard library functions.