# dylib 'File not Found' vba Excel Mac 2016

Tags: vba, macos, excel-2016, dylib

I followed this [Tutorial](https://blackcatsoftware.us/dynamic-libraries-dylib-for-office-using-xcode-5/) to create a dylib library using Xcode. I also followed the instructions in [Calling dylib functions in Office for Mac VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470863/calling-dylib-functions-in-office-for-mac-vba). The first Tutorial is not clear as to where the compiled library is, so I moved the .dylib file in the directory */Build/Products/Debug/* to Macintosh HD⁩:Users⁩:[User]:Library⁩:Group Containers⁩:UBF8T346G9.Office⁩, so my vba code is:

```
   Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function myAdd Lib "Users:[user]:Library:Group Containers:UBF8T346G9.Office:libcanaimalibc.dylib" Alias "_Z3addii" (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare PtrSafe Function myDivide Lib "Users:[user]:Library:Group Containers:UBF8T346G9.Office:libcanaimalibc.dylib" Alias "_Z6dividedd" (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare PtrSafe Function myMultiply Lib "Users:[user]:Library:Group Containers:UBF8T346G9.Office:libcanaimalibc.dylib" Alias "_Z8multiplyii" (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare PtrSafe Function mySubtract Lib "Users:[user]:Library:Group Containers:UBF8T346G9.Office:libcanaimalibc.dylib" Alias "_Z8subtractii" (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer

Function Addition(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
Addition = myAdd(a, b)
End Function
Function Subtract(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
Subtract = mySubtract(a, b)
End Function
Function Multiply(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
Multiply = myMultiply(a, b)
End Function
Function Divide(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
Divide = myDivide(a, b)
End Function
```

When I test

> ? Addition(2,3)

in the intermediate window I get the error message:

[image]

Comment: The path might be failing because there's a space within "Group Containers", although it looks like a POSIX type path, so in theory it shouldn't. Maybe try renaming the location `GroupContainers` if possible.

Comment: I tried calling the library to folder **/Users/[User]/Library/Developer/Build/Products/Debug/** and got the same message.

Comment: I tried calling libc.dylib in ./usr/lib, i.e., **Private Declare PtrSafe Function system Lib "Macintosh HD:usr:lib:libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long** and got the same 'File not found' error. Excel's vba should be looking at a specific directory where libraries should be placed in.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Full path didn't work for me. Placed dylib in folder **Macintosh HD⁩/Users⁩/[user]/Library⁩/Containers⁩/com.microsoft.Excel⁩/Data⁩**. Called library in VBA:

`Private Declare PtrSafe Function [function] _
Lib "[name].dylib" Alias "[mangled name]" _
(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As String) As String`

And now it works.